# Insert records into Access database produces blank rows

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to insert records into my Access database using the following code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim sqlString As String

    Sub page_load()
        Try
            txtFName.Text = ""
            txtLName.Text = ""

            dbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("MyDatabase.accdb"))
            dbConnection.Open()

            sqlString = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ID"
            dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)
            dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

            While dbReader.Read()
                Dim lblName As Label = New Label()
                lblName.ID = dbReader("ID")
                lblName.Text = "<b>Name: </b>" & dbReader("F_Name") & " " & dbReader("L_Name") & "<br/><br/>"
                lblName.EnableViewState = False
                nameArea.Controls.Add(lblName)
            End While

            dbReader.Close()
        Finally
            dbConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub addToDatabase()
        Try
            dbConnection.Open()
            sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 (F_Name,L_Name) VALUES (@FName, @LName)"
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFName.Text)
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLName.Text)
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Finally
            dbConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
</script>
```

In my asp code below, I have two TextBoxes to hold first name and last name, as well as a button that will call addToDatabase when clicked, and a placeholder to display each record pulled from the database:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="addToDatabase" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="nameArea" runat="server" />
```

My access database contains a table named table1, with an ID, F_Name and L_Name field, with their DataTypes being AutoNumber, Text and Text respectively.

My problem is when I click btnSubmit, it adds blank records into my database for F_Name and L_Name instead of what was in the TextBoxes, and continues to add blank records on every browser refresh.

What is going on?

Comment: Would like to see your `Page_Load` code too, please post.

Comment: Edited it in for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my code around and added a new Sub that will get names, then called that method on initial page_load and after calling addToDatabase. I kept everything else in the asp below the same.

```
Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader
Dim sqlString As String

Sub page_load()
    dbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("MyDatabase.accdb"))
    dbCommand = New OleDbCommand("", dbConnection)

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        showNames()
    End If
End Sub

Sub showNames()
    Try
        dbConnection.Open()

        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ID"
        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

        While dbReader.Read()
            Dim lblName As Label = New Label()
            lblName.ID = dbReader("ID")
            lblName.Text = "<b>Name: </b>" & dbReader("F_Name") & " " & dbReader("L_Name") & "<br/>"
            lblEntry.EnableViewState = False
            nameArea.Controls.Add(lblName)
        End While

        dbReader.Close()
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Sub addToDatabase(src As Object, args as EventArgs)
    Try
        dbConnection.Open()
        sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 (F_Name,L_Name) VALUES (@FName, @LName)"
        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFName.Text)
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLName.Text)
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try

    showNames()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines from your `page_load` method.

```
        txtFName.Text = ""
        txtLName.Text = ""
```

Add the following at the end of the `addToDatabase` method. This will then show you the new names in the page without needing a call to the database.

```
Dim lblName As Label = New Label()
lblName.ID = dbReader("ID")
lblName.Text = "<b>Name: </b>" & txtFName.Text & " " & txtLName.Text & "<br/><br/>"
lblName.EnableViewState = False
nameArea.Controls.Add(lblName)
```

Comment: Doing this gives me a System.NullReferenceException when attempting to close dbConnection in addToDatabase.

Comment: Open the connection inside `addToDatabase`. Add `dbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("MyDatabase.accdb"))
            dbConnection.Open()` to the method.

Comment: Isn't adding multiple initializations for the same object considered bad practice? Also, on postbacks it no longer shows the records pulled from my database.

Comment: See my updated answer. I think you need to just remove couple of lines.

Comment: Removing those lines adds their contents to the database now, however the new record isn't displayed on the page until the next page_load. Is there a way I can possibly make the button not do a postback, and force a postback at the end of the addToDatabase procedure?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The new name is already displayed in the textboxes. But if you want, then why don't you just add the names to the `lblName`?

Comment: I think the page_load is happening before addToDatabase is, so I don't see the newly added data until the next page_load.

Comment: addToDatabase can't access dbReader.